# PHP Facebook Image Proxy

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to figure out how to create a simple image proxy for Facebook.   The end goal is to be authenticated as myself with my access token saved, used the Facebook PHP lib to grab photos that I am tagged in, and then display those on my wordpress site.

I've got everything working, I just need to figure out how to show these images via a proxy so users who are not authenticated / do not have access normally to see them will be able to.

I'm looking for something that is basically:   img src="/fb-proxy.php?uid=some-fb-photo-id"

I don't want to download the files on to my server, but want to do this all on the fly in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could swap `$json_details['picture']` for `$json_details['source']` if you wanted the original version of the photo.

```
<?php
$access_token = 'HARD CODED ACCESS TOKEN';
$picture_id = $_REQUEST['pid'];
$json_details = json_decode(
  file_get_contents(
    "https://graph.facebook.com/".$picture_id."?access_token=".$access_token), 
    true);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$picture = $json_details['picture'];
echo file_get_contents($picture);
?>
```

You could call this just as your suggest, but instead use `pid` instead of `uid`, where `pid` is a facebook photo id.